# What would happen if we do `git push master` when having multiple remotes?

Tags: git

What is the effect of `git push master` if I have multiple remotes? 
Is it going to be equivalent to `git push origin master`?

Answer (score 2):

You will get an error because you likely don't have a repository with name "master". If you only pass a single argument, it is interpreted as the name of the remote repository, not the branch.

This is also evident from the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

```
git push ... [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `git push` only. If you set the upstream reference, it'll be pushed. Use `git push -u` to set the upstream reference.